# C linker behaves strange gives unresolved externals where it shouldn't

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with linking a program, the strange thing about that is that functions that linker can't resolve, sit in the same file near the functions that are resolved without a problem.

I can't post files themselves in the message as they are pretty large, though ===> [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByVHzYDa6azxYlVxR0FpdVFheHM) <=== is the project ready to be built.

Here are build errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _leveldb_filterpolicy_destroy referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _leveldb_options_set_filter_policy referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _leveldb_filterpolicy_create_bloom referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _leveldb_filterpolicy_create referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _leveldb_filterpolicy_create referenced in function _main
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEz76.png) is the full-size screenshot showing error messages
[image]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbkrh.png) is the implementation of the function that cant be found:
[image]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMZh2.png) is the implementation of the function that sits in the same file and is easily found by the linker:
[image]

Comment: Just a thought - the parameter for the missing functions isn't using some kind of PIMPL idiom, is it?

Comment: see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer Basically it means that leveldb_filter_polict_t would be just `void*` or similar as far as the outside world is concerned, but in the implementation of the function some #ifdef magic make it a pointer to the actual struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found-out what was causing the problem, I've updated the version of leveldb to a newer one. The newer version introduced several new functions (the ones that are being unresolved). But I haven't updated the .def file which contains all exports, and functions weren't exported as a result...